# How to save an Image emitted by Jetpack Compose as a Bitmap

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using GlideImage with Jetpack compose, once the image is finished loading I would like to save it as a Bitmap. In XML this was quite straight forward, we would do something like this:

```
val bmp: Bitmap = image_view.drawToBitmap() //image_view is the XML id of the ImageView
```

What is the jetpack compose equivalent of this?

Comment: Why do you need to save it as a Bitmap?

Comment: I would like to save the Bitmap -> then covert it to a ByteArray -> Pass the ByteArray as Intent Extras while navigating to another Activity -> Convert ByteArray to Bitmap again in the new Activity and use it as a Placeholder photo for imageView in the New Actvity while the high res photo downloads from the network in the background

Comment: Glide offers memory and disk caching. [Memory caching is enabled by default](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#memory-cache). So, pass the `Uri` or filesystem path of your image from activity to activity. Have the other activity simply load the image normally via Glide, and Glide will get the image out of cache. This will be much less memory intensive than is your plan, which will make a few redundant copies of the image. It is also less code and will consume less CPU time.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for the suggestion, I ve done exactly that